# How do I write a Lamdda function in AWS that allows me to connect to an EC2 instance that is running MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an EC2 instance, installed and configured MySQL on it (not RDS), I have created a database (`airpollutiondata`) and a table named (`CO2`).

I am trying to write a Lambda function (running node.js) that will connect to MySQL (which is running on my EC2 instance) and run a select statement to pull some data.

I have tried everything that I can think of (sample code below without the select statement).

I am hoping that someone might be able to steer me in the correct direction. Here is the code that I have tested unsuccessfully in AWS Lamda.

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({ 
host: "localhost", 
user: "yourusername", 
password: "yourpassword", 
database: 'airpollutiondata' 
}); 
con.connect(function(err) { 
if (err) throw err; 
console.log("Connected!"); 
});
```

I tried to find resources online that would steer me in the correct direction, but everything seems to be geared towards using RDS with MySql (unfortunately this isn't the way that I set this up)

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide any information about what exactly does happen. But I will assume that your code does work except for the `host` field, where you need to replace `localhost` with the private IP address of your instance.

- Make sure that mysql does listen on all interfaces - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43025/how-to-allow-mysql-remote-connections-via-particular-interface
- An AWS lambda does not have by default any access to your VPC, which means it has no way how to connect there. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html
- Make sure that the security group you assign to your lambda can create outbound connections to your EC2.
- Make sure that the security group you assign to your EC2 accepts connection from security group of your lambda.

Comment: Hi Petrch. Thank you so much for your reply. Unfortunately, my code does not seem to work at all. I have made the configuration changes located here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html. I am checking my security groups now.

Comment: I would suggest to debug the code on your ec2 machine - that way you will know that your code does work and then when you put it inside a lambda you know that any problem should be in the infrastructure - just keep an eye on the 'host' parameter.